# Помогите исправить ошибку Access "Ambigious name detected"

Tags: access

В общем-то, истоки проблемы понятны: я как-то создал кнопку с названием "Расписание далее" для переключения между записями, но потом понял, что случайно задал не ту команду и удалил её. На её месте я создал кнопку с таким же названием, но уже правильной и командой. И тут же появилась та ошибка. Не долго думмая, я удалил и эту кнопку, и создал другую с другим названием, но эта зараза перекочевала на все кнопки, и теперь у меня даже главная кнопочная форма не работает под предлогом. что где-то там когда-то у меня были две кнопки с одинаковым названием. Как мне это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, ларчик просто открывался - при нажатии на описание ошибки открылось окно кода, откуда я просто удалил описание этих кнопок.